# what is way to download image from libxml?

Tags: iphone, libxml2

i here that libxml parsing is fast and for that downloading image is a some particular way to download .

i want that method for download .

i have some code for this . like this but cant understand ..

i got code is like this ,,,

```
[networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(imageFetchComplete:)];
[networkQueue setDelegate:self];
request =[[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[objXML.District_Photo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation]]] autorelease];
//cell.imgCell.tag=indexPath.row+1;
request.username=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row+1];
[networkQueue addOperation:request];
[networkQueue go];
```

but how it download image and how is working ..i am totaly blank about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the quick and dirty method:

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

If you want to keep using your network queuing stuff, you'll have to do that stuff in your `imageFetchComplete` method and use something like this:

```
NSData *imgData = request.responseData; 
//I think that's what the property's called. It's in the documentation

UIImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```